# How can I filter the physicalserver if its id is in the given param?

Tags: python, django

How can I filter the physicalserver if its id is in the given param?

```
class PhysicalServerListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PhysicalServerListSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsSuperAdminOrObjEqualsSelf]
    pagination_class = CommonPagination
    def get_queryset(self):

        query_params = self.request.query_params

        qs = PhysicalServer.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

        id_list = get_param_from_query_params(query_params, 'id_list')

        if id_list:
            qs = qs.filter(Q(id__in=id_list)) # I want to filter if the physicalserver id is in the `id_list`

        return qs
```

the code of the method:

```
def get_param_from_query_params(query_params, param):
    """
    :param query_params:
    :param param:
    :return:
    """
    param_temp = None

    try:
        mutable = query_params._mutable
        query_params._mutable = True

        param_list = query_params.pop(param)
        param_temp = param_list[0] if (isinstance(param_list, list) and len(param_list) > 0) else ''

        query_params._mutable = mutable
    except Exception as e:
        pass

    return param_temp
```

How can I filter the physicalserver if its id is in the given param?

---

**EDIT-1**

My id_list in the url form is:

```
id_list[]=24&id_list[]=25&id_list[]=27
```

Comment: what does your query return now? also try to remove `Q()` expression.

Comment: What are the query parameters? I doubt you need that get_param_from_query_params function.

Comment: @DanielRoseman In the post, bro.

Comment: @Chiefir the `id__in=id_list` is written by me, I don't think this is correct.

Comment: you think or you tested that it is wrong? And I mean - try replace `Q(id__in=id_list)` with `id__in=id_list`

Comment: @qg_java_17137 no it isn't. I want to know what is actually being passed to the view in the request so that I can understand what get_param_from_query_params is doing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Oh, the url can not pass list, alright?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get id_list method should be:

```
id_list = query_params.getlist('id_list')
```

This is the answer.